# Find the Week from a date passed as input oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle12c

DB : Oracle
Version : 12c

I have to find the week number as on current date based on/from the input Date.
Say, my input date is 03/Nov/2019, the query should return week number as 10.

since there are 10 weeks between today date (01/Jan/2020) and input date (03/Nov/2019).

Answer (score 5):

How about taking the difference in days and dividing by 7?

```
select floor((sysdate - date '2019-11-03') / 7) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the date mask when converting to char:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'WW') from dual;
```

Then you can add or subtract with the following example:

```
select to_char(to_date('2019-11-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'WW'), to_char(sysdate, 'WW'),
case 
  when to_char(to_date('2019-11-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'WW') > to_char(sysdate, 'WW') then
    (52 - to_char(to_date('2019-11-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'WW')) + to_char(sysdate, 'WW')
  else to_char(sysdate, 'WW') - to_char(to_date('2019-11-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'WW')
end case
from dual;
```